# How to launch a windows store 8.1 app from a browser in with a url and pass some data to the app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, url-scheme

Hi am developing a Windows store 8.1 app using C# and xaml. I get the some configuration settings in my mail with a URL, which are lets say host address, port number, and some app id. When i click on the url it should open my app and fill the settings in the app(Defaultly am launching Configuration page in my app which contains three textboxes, those three values should pre populate here)
Is it possible to do it Winrt 8.1? If so how can i achieve it? Can someone please help me out to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First you need to handle URI activation.
In your manifest, add a Protocol and reserve a Name(here is alsdk). You can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx) for more information.

[image]

Then please override OnActivated event in App.xaml.cs (receive params here).

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
}
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        // Retrieves the activation Uri.
        var protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)args;
        var uri = protocolArgs.Uri.ToString();

    }
}
```

After that you can launch your app with params in the browser:
[image]

As for passing params,please refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#accepting-arguments).